# Laravel log level, how is different?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, logging

I can see few log options in Laravel 5.4 such as

```
Log::emergency($message);
Log::alert($message);
Log::critical($message);
Log::error($message);
Log::warning($message);
Log::notice($message);
Log::info($message);
Log::debug($message);
```

And I can change log level in `app.php` at `'log_level' => env('APP_LOG_LEVEL', 'debug'),` to any kind of level I want.

But I was wondering that, what is different? What kind of log has been wirtten when one of `critical, alert, emergency` is selected?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/errors, see "Log Severity Levels"

Comment: What do you mean, “What kind of log has been wirtten”? Only _one_ log file gets written, and messages of which severity level make it into that log is what you configure by setting the log_level ...

Comment: I know, but those word is not clear that what kind of error will be written for each log levels

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When you set the log level, only the level big or equal than the setted level will be logged.

You can refer to the [laravel doc **log-severity-levels**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/errors#log-severity-levels),

> When using Monolog, log messages may have different levels of severity. By default, Laravel writes all log levels to storage.
>   However, in your production environment, you may wish to configure the
>   minimum severity that should be logged by adding the log_level option
>   to your app.php configuration file.
>
> **Once this option has been configured, Laravel will log all levels greater than or equal to the specified severity.** For example,
>   a default log_level of error will log error, critical, alert, and
>   emergency messages:
>
> ```
> 'log_level' => env('APP_LOG_LEVEL', 'error'),
> ```
>
> Monolog recognizes the following severity levels - from least severe to most severe: debug, info, notice, warning, error, critical,
>   alert, emergency.

Comment: Its been available since Laravel 5.2.45 .. you just need to add `'log_level' => env('APP_LOG_LEVEL', 'error'),` to the app.php file (and the .env if you want)